# Regex in R: How to extract certain letters from alphanumeric element in character vector?

Tags: regex, r

Say, for instance, I have the following character vector of alphanumeric elements that include state abbreviations somewhere within the element:

```
strings <- c("0001AZ226", "0001CA243", "0NA01CT134", "0001CT1NA", "0001ID112", "NAVA230")
```

How can I extract the letters, excluding NA? I.e.,

```
somefunction(strings)
[1] "AZ"  "CA"  "CT"  "CT"  "ID"  "VA"
```

I've used regular expressions before to remove all non-integers per element, but never to remove all numbers and just letters N and A.

This is what I tried, but it didn't work:

```
 sub(paste(LETTERS[c(2:13,15:26)], collapse = "|"), "", strings, fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: `gsub('\\d|NA', '', strings)` `\d` is short for digits, see `?regex` for others

Comment: Could be done with lookarounds if R supports that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
gsub("\\d+|NA", "", strings)
# [1] "AZ" "CA" "CT" "CT" "ID" "VA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done using looarounds.

```
 # (?i)(?:(?!na|(?<=n)(?=a))[a-z])+

 (?i)           # Case insensitive modifier (or use as regex flag)
 (?:            # Cluster group
      (?!            # Negative assertion
           na             # Not NA ahead
        |  (?<= n )       # Not N behind,
           (?= a )        # and A ahead (at this location) 
      )              # End Negative assertion
      [a-z]          # Safe, grab this single character
 )+             # End Cluster group, do 1 to many times
```

Matches only these `"AZ"  "CA"  "CT"  "CT"  "ID"  "VA"`

Answer (score 1):

The `state` dataset is available  by default. Looks at:

```
 ?state

sts <- paste(state.abb,collapse="|")

sub(paste0( "(.+)(", sts, ")(.+)"), "\\2", strings)
[1] "AZ" "CA" "CT" "CT" "ID" "VA"
```

Somebody tried to edit this and put in a call to `dput(states.abb)` and then pasted that into a new assignment. Given that `state` is always available, that is completely unnecessary, hence my rejection. The only value I can see might be in suggesting that people actually look at the help page and in illustrating what state.abb looks like:

```
?state
dput(state.abb)
#c("AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", 
... snipped the rest.
```

Comment: @BondedDust This is a very elegant solution! Was not aware of the `state` dataset either. Thanks.

Comment: @BondedDust you missed the point of my edit. DC is NOT in `state.abb`. Perhaps some of my edit got cut off? I explicitly said "if you want to extend this solution to DC, American territories, etc".

Comment: If you want to extend the vector to the abbreviations to postal designations for districts, protectorates, non-state commonwealths, military units, and "territories" (which for the US seems slightly archaic to my ears), wouldn't it have been easier just to use: `c(state.abb, "DC", "PR","VI","GU","MP","AA","AE","AP", "FM","MH","PW")`

Answer (score 1):

Provided the states occur followed only by three characters.

```
strings.stripped <- gsub("([A-Z]{2}).{3}$", "\\1", strings)
```